# java JTable how to track rows

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable which is connected to sqlite. The db table looks like this:

```
 resource_id #primary_key, file, type
```

I have already implemented adding the rows from db, but the problem is i need to know the resource id when some row in jTable is selected (not the index). Is there a way to add rows with unique ids and not based on indexes (or something similar)?

The current solution adds the resource id as a table column, but that doesnt solve the problem completely.

Comment: _The current solution adds the resource id as a table column, but that doesnt solve the problem completely._ Why doesn't it solve the problem completely?

Comment: Keep the `resource_id` in your `TableModel`, just don't display it. Also, please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that your current approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class say `TableData` that contains the data from the table. Use a custom `TableModel` and place the data for the JTable in `Vector<TableData>`.

You may find it useful to create a method such as `addRow(TableData data)` in your `TableModel` that process the data from the table and adds data to the `Vector`.

In the overridden method `public removeRow(int row)` you will need to remove the vector data  where row can serve as the index.

The overridden method `public Object getValueAt(int row, int col)` which is used to display the data in the JTable will then just need to retrieve the data from the `Vector<TableData>`. You can also place the logic for other columns which not part of the `TableData` in this method.

Dont forget to call fireTableRowsUpdated(row,col) and fireTableCellUpdated(row,col) where ever applicable.

For further reference and how to handling the selections in `JTable` you can refer [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection)